# doing BD scan for the docker images

Tags: blackduck

I am doing BD scan for my docker image like below

```
SYNOPSIS_DETECT_SCRIPT=$(curl --insecure -s -L https://detect.synopsys.com/detect8.sh)
bash -c "${SYNOPSIS_DETECT_SCRIPT}" --detect.docker.image='mylocalimage:latest' --blackduck.url=<URL> --detect.project.name=<Project> --detect.project.version.name="release/myimage" --blackduck.api.token=<token> --logging.level.com.synopsys.integration=DEBUG --detect.timeout=10000 --detect.tools.excluded=BINARY_SCAN --detect.blackduck.signature.scanner.memory=16384 --detect.accuracy.required=NONE
```

If I perform the BD scan from my local UBUNTU shell I am able to see the result in blackduck repo but If i perform the same from azure pipelines, The status is success but report not uploaded to the blackduck repo.